# Problem upgrading from 7.22

Tags: 7, updating

I'm trying to update from Drupal 7.22 to the current (7.26) version. I keep getting the following error on the Configuration page after updating.

`Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseTasks_mysql' not found in /server/path/stuff/here/domainname.com/html/modules/system/system.install on line 188`

I have tried upgrading incrementally 7.22 -> 7.23
I've tried upgrading directly to 7.26
I've tried uploading files via FTP, following the standard upgrade instructions, and I've tried upgrading with drush. I always get the same error. (though the line number does change depending on which version I'm updating to.)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you're site is still responding I would check for core hacks: https://drupal.org/project/hacked  Also, what version of drush are you using? `drush --version`

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this problem on two different test servers (different Debian and PHP versions) using data imported from our production server. All of the cache tables were emptied first, and I did try reinstalling Drupal using various methods. Couldn't find a solution anywhere.

What finally fixed it for me was emptying the registry and registry_file tables, then running update.php.  (Update didn't find any database changes, but it reset the registry - clearing the cache may have worked as well.)

Hope this helps someone - this problem was driving me crazy for two days.

Comment: Thanks, emptying both registry and registry_file tables and then run update.php worked for me! Best solution for this problem (because it's so fast to do it).

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating through 'drush pm-update drupal', I would try updating the files manually through git or 'drush dl', then running drush updb or update.php. If you are updating though git, make sure a merge conflict didn't butcher anything.

Class "DatabaseTasks" is declared in includes/database/mysql/install.inc which shouldn't have changed in years. Check that the file still exits and is identical to the one before.

Otherwise, it is most likely an issue with bootstrap level. If the site is not bootstrapping high enough, it will break. A bug or hack in drush or core could cause a site to bootstrap to too low a level.